# Mounting LVM partition on a RAID1 disk from a bricked QNAP NAS

Tags: lvm, raid1, qnap

I have a QNAP HS-251+ NAS with two 3TB WD Red NAS Hard Drives in RAID1 configuration. I'm quite acquainted with Linux and CLI tools, but never used mdadm or LVM so, despite knowing (now) that QNAP uses them, I have no expertise, or even knowledge about how QNAP manages to create the RAID1 assemble.
Some weeks ago, during a firmware update, the NAS stopped booting. I'm on my way to solve that problem, but I would like to recover my data before attempting to plug my disks again in the NAS (QNAP HelpDesk has been basically useless).

I expected to be able to mount the partition easily simply plugin one of the disks on my laptop (Kubuntu), but that was when I discovered that things were more complex than that.

This is the relevant information I managed to extract:

```
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$ sudo dmesg
[...]
[17272.730964] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[17272.884120] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=059b, idProduct=0475, bcdDevice= 0.00
[17272.884138] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=5
[17272.884144] usb 3-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[17272.884149] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[17272.884153] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: DCC4108FFFFF
[17272.891498] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[17272.892117] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[17273.907765] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD30 EFRX-68EUZN0          PQ: 0 ANSI: 2 CCS
[17273.908085] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[17273.908261] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] 1565565872 512-byte logical blocks: (802 GB/747 GiB)
[17273.909041] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[17273.909046] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 34 00 00 00
[17273.909789] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[17273.976961] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$
```

```
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc
Disk /dev/sdc: 746,52 GiB, 801569726464 bytes, 1565565872 sectors
Disk model: EFRX-68EUZN0    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Dispositivo Boot Start        End    Sectors Size Id Tipo
/dev/sdc1            1 4294967295 4294967295   2T ee GPT
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/
mount: /mnt: special device /dev/sdc1 does not exist.
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$
```

```
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$ sudo parted -l
[...]
Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on /dev/sdc
Retry/Ignore/Cancel? i                                                    
Error: The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.
OK/Cancel? ok                                                             
Model: WDC WD30 EFRX-68EUZN0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 802GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags: 

xabi@XV-XPS15:~$
```

```
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$ sudo lsblk 
[...]
sdc      8:32   0 746,5G  0 disk 
xabi@XV-XPS15:~$
```

Using the free version of a commercial tool (UFS RAID Recovery) I've obtained advanced information about the partitions on the disk:
[image: Disk Information]

and even recovered the lvm backup config

```
# Generated by LVM2 version 2.02.138(2)-git (2015-12-14): Fri Feb 11 09:43:53 2022

contents = "Text Format Volume Group"
version = 1

description = "Created *after* executing '/sbin/vgchange vg288 --addtag cacheVersion:3'"

creation_host = "XV-NAS"    # Linux XV-NAS 5.10.60-qnap #1 SMP Tue Dec 21 10:57:31 CST 2021 x86_64
creation_time = 1644569033  # Fri Feb 11 09:43:53 2022

vg288 {
    id = "g0F3zh-N3aN-1vEQ-qYU4-6Jhv-xgLC-d4hU43"
    seqno = 199
    format = "lvm2"         # informational
    status = ["RESIZEABLE", "READ", "WRITE"]
    flags = []
    tags = ["PV:DRBD", "PoolType:Static", "StaticPoolRev:2", "cacheVersion:3"]
    extent_size = 8192      # 4 Megabytes
    max_lv = 0
    max_pv = 0
    metadata_copies = 0

    physical_volumes {

        pv0 {
            id = "ZcFzMw-ZgzA-fOr0-FGgI-E3hc-uwKu-GzWSKn"
            device = "/dev/drbd1"   # Hint only

            status = ["ALLOCATABLE"]
            flags = []
            dev_size = 5840621112   # 2.71975 Terabytes
            pe_start = 2048
            pe_count = 712966   # 2.71975 Terabytes
        }
    }

    logical_volumes {

        lv544 {
            id = "NRzjb8-Dgw4-oHSj-rjtF-2e8H-KQZ2-YPRre3"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            creation_host = "NAS0D80FB"
            creation_time = 1494716166  # 2017-05-14 00:56:06 +0200
            read_ahead = 8192
            segment_count = 1

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 7129 # 27.8477 Gigabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 0
                ]
            }
        }

        lv1 {
            id = "1ND0gN-Lcgx-ALcO-Ui17-hzzg-2soX-LGr1rl"
            status = ["READ", "WRITE", "VISIBLE"]
            flags = []
            creation_host = "NAS0D80FB"
            creation_time = 1494716174  # 2017-05-14 00:56:14 +0200
            read_ahead = 8192
            segment_count = 1

            segment1 {
                start_extent = 0
                extent_count = 705837   # 2.69255 Terabytes

                type = "striped"
                stripe_count = 1    # linear

                stripes = [
                    "pv0", 7129
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Despite that, I haven't been able to mount the relevant volume (vg288-lv1). As I said, I'm not familiar with LVM, there are some inconsistencies with what I've seen in other posts (no sdc1 device, parted can't find the partitions, the reported size doesn't match the real one...) and I'm not sure how to start to solve this methodically.

I've tried using the backup config as a template to restore the lvm volumes and failed, but, as I said, I'm not sure that I'm doing things correctly, so I feel I need some guiding on where to start, as the results of my tests until now will only add confusion.
Thanks.

## UPDATE:

As @user7138814 suggested, it seems that the WD30EFRX is an "Advanced Format" disk, meaning 4k (physical) sectors, and some SATA-USB adapters don't support this. Mine was old, so I got a new one, and all the weird inconsistences dissapeared:

```
# dmesg
[...]
[74820.751587] usb 4-1: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[74820.779219] usb 4-1: New USB device found, idVendor=174c, idProduct=1153, bcdDevice= 1.00
[74820.779235] usb 4-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[74820.779241] usb 4-1: Product: Ugreen Storage Device
[74820.779245] usb 4-1: Manufacturer: Ugreen
[74820.779249] usb 4-1: SerialNumber: 26A1EE833D7E
[74820.787123] scsi host7: uas
[74820.788495] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD30 EFRX-68EUZN0     0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[74820.789417] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[74820.789908] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 5860533168 512-byte logical blocks: (3.00 TB/2.73 TiB)
[74820.789918] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[74820.790061] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[74820.790067] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[74820.790252] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[74820.790688] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[74820.849288]  sdd: sdd1 sdd2 sdd3 sdd4 sdd5
[74820.891810] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

```
# fdisk -l /dev/sdd
Disk /dev/sdd: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: EFRX-68EUZN0    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EA97E765-8FD0-4C41-8AEA-8B7570F42D68

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1          40    1060289    1060250 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd2     1060296    2120579    1060284 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd3     2120584 5842744109 5840623526   2.7T Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd4  5842744112 5843804399    1060288 517.7M Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd5  5843804408 5860511999   16707592     8G Microsoft basic data
```

```
# lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sdd      8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk 
|-sdd1   8:49   0 517.7M  0 part 
|-sdd2   8:50   0 517.7M  0 part 
|-sdd3   8:51   0   2.7T  0 part 
|-sdd4   8:52   0 517.7M  0 part 
`-sdd5   8:53   0     8G  0 part
```

## SOLUTION

Following loosely the instructions on https://forum.qnap.com/viewtopic.php?t=156819 , I managed to mount the partition and recover the data. This are the steps I followed:

Force mdadm to examine the disk:

```
# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/9  metadata=1.0 UUID=2b29da4f:f725eb04:e2ac3e60:37023bbd name=9
ARRAY /dev/md/256  metadata=1.0 UUID=ed18a26a:4e9ca5f1:aca74d2f:99cb409b name=256
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.0 UUID=111bee9e:d34c75c0:87822b63:fbcd271d name=1
ARRAY /dev/md/13  metadata=1.0 UUID=d410ebe5:a4158d63:08559db0:795abb11 name=13
ARRAY /dev/md/322  metadata=1.0 UUID=4bd0cd6d:fcc98341:329fab8c:a32f5495 name=322
```

Check that the raid array was recgnized:

```
# lsblk
NAME      MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
[...]
sdd         8:48   0   2.7T  0 disk  
|-sdd1      8:49   0 517.7M  0 part  
|-sdd2      8:50   0 517.7M  0 part  
|-sdd3      8:51   0   2.7T  0 part  
| `-md127   9:127  0   2.7T  0 raid1 
|-sdd4      8:52   0 517.7M  0 part  
`-sdd5      8:53   0     8G  0 part
```

```
# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdd3[1]
      2920311616 blocks super 1.0 [2/1] [_U]
      
md123 : inactive sdc1[1]
      530108 blocks super 1.0
       
md124 : inactive sdc5[1]
      8353780 blocks super 1.0
       
md125 : inactive sdc2[1]
      530124 blocks super 1.0
       
md126 : inactive sdc4[1]
      530128 blocks super 1.0
       
unused devices: <none>
```

Identify the Physical volumes. Ignore warning:

```
# pvdisplay 
  WARNING: PV /dev/md127 in VG vg288 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/md127
  VG Name               vg288
  PV Size               <2.72 TiB / not usable <1.78 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              712966
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          712966
  PV UUID               ZcFzMw-ZgzA-fOr0-FGgI-E3hc-uwKu-GzWSKn
```

Identify volume group:

```
# vgdisplay vg288
  WARNING: PV /dev/md127 in VG vg288 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg288
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  199
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <2.72 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              712966
  Alloc PE / Size       712966 / <2.72 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               g0F3zh-N3aN-1vEQ-qYU4-6Jhv-xgLC-d4hU43
```

Identify the logical volumes:

```
# lvdisplay 
  WARNING: PV /dev/md127 in VG vg288 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg288/lv544
  LV Name                lv544
  VG Name                vg288
  LV UUID                NRzjb8-Dgw4-oHSj-rjtF-2e8H-KQZ2-YPRre3
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time NAS0D80FB, 2017-05-14 00:56:06 +0200
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                <27.85 GiB
  Current LE             7129
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     8192
   
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/vg288/lv1
  LV Name                lv1
  VG Name                vg288
  LV UUID                1ND0gN-Lcgx-ALcO-Ui17-hzzg-2soX-LGr1rl
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time NAS0D80FB, 2017-05-14 00:56:14 +0200
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                2.69 TiB
  Current LE             705837
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     8192
```

Activate the required volume:

```
# lvchange -ay /dev/vg288/lv1
  WARNING: PV /dev/md127 in VG vg288 is using an old PV header, modify the VG to update.
```

Mount and check that its accesible:

```
# mount -t ext4 -o ro /dev/vg288/lv1 /mnt

# ls /mnt
Container  Multimedia  Public   Web              core-hal_callhome_co  core-hal_lvm_check   hal_daemon_seg_fault.log  lost+found
Download   Musica      Samples  aquota.user      core-hal_daemon       core-hal_netlink     homes                     qsync-homes
Imaxes     Pelis       Series   aquota.user.new  core-hal_enc_reset    hal_daemon_fail.log  htdocs
```

Comment: In Ubuntu or other Debian derivated distro, you need to install the necessary packages: madam and lvm2. With those packages installed, when you connect your disk through USB the volume will be autodetected and you can mount it. If you use some forensic distro - Kali, CAINE ... - they have the RAID/LVM support already installed.

Comment: I've madam and lvm2 installed (my bad not pointing it). It does not recognize the volume, though. But I'll try the forensic distro route, didn't think about that. Good advice, thanks.

Comment: As I do not know detail of your Qnap model, I cannot be sure that the next comment is relevant, but some Qnap use ARM or Power CPU hence they may use BigEndian number representation. In that case you need to read man mdadm carefully, and write the raid assembly manually with correcting param. Try to inspect the disk with `mdadm --examine /dev/sdX` first. (Sorry, the stupid spell corrector miscorrect mdadm to madam :-/ )

Comment: It's an Intel one, don't expect that to be the issue. But I don't discard any weird behavior either, QNAP QTS seems a little odd

Comment: There is something peculiar in the dmesg and RAID-recovery: they see the disk just 802 GB/747 GiB in total capacity?!? Also `parted` did not find the backup GPT table, which is usually at the end of disk. May the disk be corrupted? Try to use the other mirrored disk. They should content nearly identical data. (`sudo parted /dev/sdc unit B print` - will show the info from partition table in bytes)

Comment: Yes, that's the first odd thing that put me on alert. But it's consistent with the other disk. This NAS has a 512 MB DOM drive where the firmware is installed, and it seems as if it's using part of the disks for other parts of the system (on the image, the block called 256 as SWAP, the block called 9 as config storage, that's where I found the lvm backup).

Comment: Well, some info comes from data stored on the disk plates, some other reside in the flash ROM as a part of firmware. You can pick up this resident info with `sudo smartctl -x /dev/sdc` either `hdparm -I /dev/sdc`. If I had a sufficient disk capacity, I definitely started with ddrescue to save the present content of the disk into the image file (or guymager with GUI), and than I try to explore the data on the image.

Comment: For some programs which do not work with image file, you can create a virtual block device with `sudo losetup -Prf diskimage.dd` and check the created device either by `sudo losetup -l` or `lsblk`.

Comment: According to the spec sheet the WD30EFRX is an "Advanced Format" disk, meaning 4k (physical) sectors. My guess is that the usb-sata adapter does not support this.

Comment: @user7138814 Yeah, that was the origin of the problem! Thanks! I got a modern SATA to USB adapter and things went smoothly. I'm adding your suggestion and the solution to the original post. Thanks to you and @schweik!